# CSS Do Not affect specific element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a CSS Style that affects all inputs in the page:

```
input[type="text"]
{
    width: 250px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    background: linear-gradient(#eee, #fff);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #555;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #ECECEC;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #ECECEC;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 4px #ECECEC;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="text"]:focus
{
    outline: none;
    background-position: 0 -1.9em;
    border: 1px #8DB1F0 solid;
}
```

However, I do not want it to affect this as the style causes some problem with this element.

```
<input id="companyname" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Use css [`:not(..)`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/) selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS [`:not(..)`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/) selector to filter out unwanted elements.

In your case,

```
input[type="text"]:not(#companyname){
    ....
}
```